# Is there a Marketplace for finding ASP.Net projects to work on?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am looking to find some good projects to work on. Is there a good site to find such projects and make decent bucks?

Answer (score 4):

A couple:

- [oDesk](http://www.odesk.com)
- [RentACoder](http://www.rentacoder.com)
- [ScriptLance](http://www.ScriptLance.com)
- [eLance](http://www.elance.com)

Comment: Thank you. Any preferences from your list?

Comment: I like oDesk, I haven't tried scriptlance or elance (just heard about them) and didn't have much luck on rentacoder

Answer (score 4):

If you are based in third-world country, try any freelancer site such as http://www.getafreelancer.com, http://www.rentacoder.com etc.

If you live in western europe or US, forget it. This is highly competitive market based on price, not quality of work and you will never be able to beat offers from programmers who can live decently on $200/week income say in India or Russia.

Comment: very true. you get outbid on everything.

Answer (score 1):

Open source:

- http://www.codeplex.com/

But you asked about paid projects.  That's what careers.stackoverflow.com is for.

Comment: outside the current job.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: No.  Because you specified "decent bucks".

Now if you're looking for a JOB that you can do remotely on an hourly basis... craigslist is the place to look.  Check out the "gigs" section.

There is also an option to search telecommuting/part time jobs on most job sites.  I like dice.com because it caters to technical jobs.